# What is the difference between resources and map.resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been using both of them for a while so I am just curious what is their difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

resources is the new DSL in Rails 3 and replace map.resources from Rails 2

Answer (score 0):

One answer could be that in rails 2.x you'd use map.resources and in rails 3.x it's just resources. You don't specify which you're using though or give any examples so it's hard to give a meaningful answer.